# Android Manifest no launcher found

Tags: android, manifest

Im working on android map API and I got it working. The problem is when add a new activity (.ListActivity) and make it my Launcher the console is giving me an error "No Launcher found". Here is my code...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.themap"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="14"
    android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

<permission
    android:name="com.example.themap.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
    android:protectionLevel="signature" />

<uses-permission android:name="com.example.themap.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />

<uses-feature
    android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
    android:required="true" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
        android:value="my_key" />

    <activity
        android:name="com.example.themap.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.themap.ListActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_list" >
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </activity>
</application>
```

Comment: yep it will work and run but I want my .ListActivity to be my launcher instead of .MainActivty

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It has to be in an intent-filter together with the MAIN.

```
<activity
   android:name="com.example.themap.ListActivity"
   android:label="@string/title_activity_list" >
   <intent-filter>
     <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
     <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
   </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

Answer (score 0):

In your second activity addition you forgot to add intent-filter tags. that is why you are getting the error.

Change your xml file second activity addition as below.

```
<activity
        android:name="com.example.themap.ListActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_list" >
<intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
</intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

Comment: Got it! I did not see that :) thank you so much. I think i need new specs hehe

Answer (score 0):

tag is missing in com.example.themap.ListActivity

Also you have more than one android.intent.action.MAIN defined

This is defined in both your activities

Refer - http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_MAIN